# editing a row in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i have a table with couple of rows 
and each row there is a button for editing that rows data

here is my table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td  class="it_name"> 1111 </td> 
<td  class="it_price"> 1111 </td> 
<td  class="it_info"> 1111 </td> 
<td  class="it_val"> 1111 </td> 
<td  class="BTN"> <INPUT TYPE="button" CLASS="edit_items" /> <td/> 
</tr>
<tr>
...
</tr>
</table>
```

in one of tds i have a button which im going to use for editing that row

firs i get value of each td on that row 
then im going to put a textfild on that td and set the value of that textfild to the old value of that td

and at last im going to change the button to another button for finalizing the edit

```
jq(function(){
jq('.edit_items').click(function(){

/////// getting value of each td                    
var  name  = jq.trim(jq(this).parent().siblings('.it_name').text());
var  price = jq.trim(jq(this).parent().siblings('.it_price').text());
var info   = jq.trim(jq(this).parent().siblings('.it_info').text());
var   av   = jq.trim(jq(this).parent().siblings('.it_av').text());

////// putting a textfild on each td

jq(this).parent().siblings('.it_name').html('<input class="it_name_f" type="text" value="'+name+'" />');

jq(this).parent().siblings('.it_price').html('<input class="it_price_f" type="text" value="'+price+'" />');

jq(this).parent().siblings('.it_info').html('<input class="it_info_f" type="text"   value="'+info+'" />');

jq(this).parent().siblings('.it_av').html('<input class="it_va_f" type="text" value="'+va+'" />'); 

 ///////// changing button                  
jq(this).parent().html('<input name="" class="final" type="button" value="edit_now" />');
})
```

now it works fine on putting textfild on the tds but for some reason it appears that i cant change my button after i changed the other tds html !
or
if i move changing button line (which is last one on this code)

```
jq(this).parent().html('<input name="" class="final" type="button" value="edit_now" />');
```

to the top of my code now the button changes but the other tds are not going to change its eather this or that ! 
am i missing something ?

Comment: This line: <INPUT TYPE="button" CLASS=""edit_items" /> has an extra double-quote before edit_items. I'm not saying that's the cause; just pointing it out. Also on your lines you have <td/> instead of </td>. Could just be broken HTML. Also, you are going to lose your click binding after you destroy and recreate your button.

Comment: Why, oh _why_, aren't you using one of the (many) existing table-editor jQuery components?

Comment: What Matt said. Alas, I've let too much time elapse to edit my own comment to be more succinct.

Comment: @gregp thnx i just wrote the table here and didn't copy/paste that part from original , it's not a problem

Comment: @ matt actually i'm going to edit this rows in the database as well it's not just a table so i wasn't sure if i could do this with a plugin and it's seems easy enough to do it my self

Comment: The best thing to do is to create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net. Save it, which creates a link, and then share it here. The code looks pretty straightforward, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very much against my better judgment, I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dTncS/3/

It took a surprising amount of work to create the fiddle because the original post did not copy/paste the code you were working on. There were typos and missing pieces that needed to be fixed before the problem could even be addressed. That's why it's always a good idea to just have sample code ready to go. Even without a sample, though, typos make it confusing to the person who would otherwise be happy to help.

In the fiddle, there's still more caching that can be done, but I wanted to keep the code in a state that more closely resembled what you've written. No point going all crazy on you. ;-)

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

jq(function() {

    var $table = jq('table');

    // any time there's a finalize button in a table, bind this to it
    $table.delegate('.final', 'click', function() {
        // do finalize stuff here
        alert('finalizing!');
    });

    // ditto for edit_items buttons. Bind this to those              
    $table.delegate('.edit_items', 'click', function() {

        var $thisParent = jq(this).parent(); // for the love of all things good and holy, cache!
        /////// getting value of each td                    
        var name = jq.trim($thisParent.siblings('.it_name').text()),
            price = jq.trim($thisParent.siblings('.it_price').text()),
            info = jq.trim($thisParent.siblings('.it_info').text()),
            av = jq.trim($thisParent.siblings('.it_av').text());

        ////// putting a textfild on each td
        $thisParent.siblings('.it_name').html('<input class="it_name_f" type="text" value="' + name + '" />');
        $thisParent.siblings('.it_price').html('<input class="it_price_f" type="text" value="' + price + '" />');
        $thisParent.siblings('.it_info').html('<input class="it_info_f" type="text"   value="' + info + '" />');
        $thisParent.siblings('.it_av').html('<input class="it_va_f" type="text" value="' + av + '" />');

        $thisParent.html('<input name="" class="final" type="button" value="finalize" />');
    });
});
```

As far as I can tell, the reason your original didn't work (even though it wasn't in production-ready state IMO) is for only one reason: you tried using a variable "va" when the variable you declared was "av". Using a JavaScript console will alert you to these kinds of problems early.

The main improvements that you should learn from are:

1. cache your jQuery objects. There's absolutely no reason to use $(this) as many times as you did when you can just cache it in a variable. Since each of your $(this)...siblings() calls are made twice, you could go even further and cache those, too. I didn't.
2. use .delegate(), especially when you know you're going to be adding and removing nodes from the DOM. It's just a lot easier.

One thing you will need to learn as you advance is to use an iterator (in jQuery, .each() is pretty easy; but there are others such as "for" and "while" loops you could take advantage of). You'll notice that each of your 4 lines getting the text are almost the same code. Then your 4 lines creating the text fields are almost the same code. You could design a piece of code that just repeats X # of times, swapping in values as they are needed.